# How to attach a number at the end of a variable to call on a locally stored variable? java

Tags: java

This is a little hard to explain but in my program I have a loop with a counter so every time the loop goes the count increases by one. The loop will run a random amount of times from 1 to 10 times and I have locally stored variables by the name variable1, variable2, variable3, etc. Let say that the loop runs three times, so the count is = 3 is there anyway to retrieve variable3 based on the count value? Like some code that is equal to variable[count]?

example:

```
String Variable1 = yes

String Variable2 = no

String Variable3 = maybe

String Variable4 = possibly

int count = 1;
while (randomnumber < 10 ){
count = count + 1;
System.out.print(Variable[count]);
```

Comment: It could be done using reflection, I imagine, but there's really no reason to. Use some kind of collection as all the answers have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can make your task easier to achieve this:

```
    String[] option={"yes", "no", "maybe", "possibly"};

    int count = 1;
    while (randomnumber < 10 && count <= option.length){ //if count is more than array option's size, arrayIndexOutOfBoundException
        count = count + 1;
        System.out.print(option[count-1]);
    }
```

Comment: To avoid that comment, I'd use option.length :) Also, count should start from 0, and you can Sop before the count + 1 so you can avoid that extra operation(count - 1).

Comment: I just follow exactly OP's code. and you're right for using `.length()` :)

Comment: Awesome thanks that works! Thanks for everyone's quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variables are Strings(you can replace with any class anyway):

```
String[] variables = { "str1", "str2", "str3" };
```

If count = 3, you need the 3rd variable, but the array is 0-indexed, so you must do it this way: variables[count - 1]. That's it.

Comment: Yes the variable3 is a string. But im confused on how to implement that. I want to do System.out.println(Variable3)

Comment: So your variables have different types? Use Object[] instead. To show a variable stored in the array, just do it like System.out.println(variables[count - 1]); count - 1 is a number, the index and will help you to get the right variable from the array. If you have custom classes, created by you, you will probably want to override toString method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List variables= new ArrayList();
variables.add("k1");
variables.add("k2");
variables.add("k3");
System.out.println("----------------"+variables.get(0)+"------------");
System.out.println("----------------"+variables.get(1)+"------------");
System.out.println("----------------"+variables.get(2)+"------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then Instead of defining different variables for different values use `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    list.add("Value at index:"+i);
}
```

To access value at the last index you can use:

```
System.out.println(list.get(list.size()-1));
```

This will give you the last value in the list:

```
Value at index:9
```

**Update1** Instead of defining seaprate varaible you can use `ArrayList` to store values and then access it using `index`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("yes");
list.add("no");
list.add("maybe");
list.add("possibly");

int count=0;
int randomNumber=7;
while (randomNumber < 10 && count<list.size()){
    count = count + 1;
    System.out.println(list.get(count-1));
}
```

Comment: But variable1 through variable10 all have string values stored in them already will that retain their value?